# C# WinForms User input from TextBox to Array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace arrays_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string[] array1;

        public ulong size = 0;

        public string input = "";

        public int counter = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            array1 = new string[1];
        }

        public void btnImposta_Click() // defines array size
        {
            ulong size = Convert.ToUInt64(textBox_ArraySize.Text); 
            array1 = new string[size];
        }

        public void btnInserisciAggiungi_Click() // button to input in array
        {
            buttonInsertAdd.Text = "Add";
            counter++;
            input = textBox_Content.Text;
            
            array1 = input; // Here's the error (I can't convert string "input" to string[] "array")

            lstArray.Items.Add(array1[counter]);

            textBox_Content.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, as the title says, I'm trying to take the user input from a TextBox, put it in an Array and finally output it on a ListBox
I don't know how to input the textbox text to the array, though.

Here's my code.

Comment: A little unclear. Do you want to append the text box text to the list box? Or split the text on some delimiter and and those results to the list box?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I've wanted to:
take input from textBox, one string at a time -> store into array all the strings -> output in listbox for each input

Comment: Ok. You don't need the array (unless you have some other use for it). The `ListBox` will be the container for all the strings. `lstArray.Items.Add(textBox_Content.Text)`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I know I don’t need an array, but I’m trying to learn something from W3Schools and I tried to make the arrays harder by asking the user for them.

Comment: Use a List and set it as the DataSource of the ListBox...

Answer (score 1):

A guy replied but the answer got deleted for some reason, writing

```
array1[counter] = input;
```

instead of

```
array1 = input;
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] enteredvalues = new string[0];

Array.Resize(ref enteredvalues, enteredvalues.Length + 1);
enteredvalues[enteredvalues.Length - 1] = "string from textbox";
```